# How to install Python 3.8.1 on RHEL 8?

Tags: python-3.x, rhel, centos8

This is really frustrating.

I want to install the latest version of Python (at the time of this issue: Python 3.8.1) on RHEL 8, (RHEL being one of the most widely used distributions of Linux).

I would like to type:
`#dnf install python`

and have it install the latest version of Python.

I can't do this, and I do not know why.

---

When I go to python.org and click on 'install for Linux' I get a link to the source code.

There are no instructions there as to what to do with the source code.

I do not understand why this is.

I don't want the source code, I want to install python 3.8.1 executables for my platform (RHEL 8).

I search on how to install python 3.8.1 from source and get a long list of dependencies that I have to install and a long list of steps.

---

Is this because it is a very rare thing for companies to run Python on Linux?

Can we get together here and make it easy for folks to install Python on Linux?

I'm willing to pay money out of my daily earnings to setup a RHEL 8 repo to get Python 3.8 there if IBM/Redhat is not willing to do this.

---

Why does the official Python organization hate Linux?

Why does IBM / Redhat hate Python?

Can we bring the two together in peace and harmony so that they just get along?

---

This is very frustrating, I should be able to knock this task out in a few seconds, and it has turned into hours.

The same amount of hours to figure out how to do this is probably done every day by developers all over the world that want to install/run the latest version of Python on Linux (CentOS / RHEL).

Comment: I recommend using pyenv. Then you can manage multiple versions of Python as well as the latest one along side one another without affecting your system Python.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.8 Application Stream is currently available with [RHEL 8.2 beta](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/red-hat-enterprise-linux-82-beta-now-available).  Since we support every new version of Python (3 years) that we release, we need to make sure that it's stable before bringing it to RHEL and the many hardware architectures it runs on. This is also important as customers expect technologies to be production grade. This table shows that over the years, we have officially supported more than one Python version [simultaneously](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl-rhel7). You can download RHEL 8.2 beta from [here](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/download). RHEL 8 was released with 2 versions of Python (2.7 and 3.6) because it's an important technology for us. We've used it ourselves for many years in building RHEL components and, among others in this industry, we had to rebuild it to 3.x (from 2.7).

FYI - new versions of Python and other components are released as Software Collections on RHEL 7, and as Application Streams on RHEL 8. The benefit of these is that the version of Python that's installed will have exactly the same packages and components for each system it's install it on. This simplifies things a lot (as you point out, it's complicated) and minimizes the "it works on my machine" issue.

Comment: @user10664542 _"I'm not sure what distortion bubble you live in"_ - Please don't be rude to someone who's trying to help you (or anyone else, for that matter). It is uncalled for, and [unwelcome here](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unacceptable-behavior).

Comment: Python releases new version [almost every year](https://devguide.python.org/versions/). Where to find packages of Python 3.11 for Red Hat 7.9 and 8.2, please?